# telnet/terminal emulation for silverlight/wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, telnet

I'm attempting to put together a telnet client for wp7 mango, so I can play some muds on my dev phone. I am having difficulty finding a decent open source terminal emulation library that will work for Silverlight (mango is roughly equivalent to the sl 4 stack). I see amuse, but that was written for wpf and sl doesn't seem to have that flow layout control it uses to display the telnet console. Any suggestions? I am already able to connect to a telnet server and get a two way stream, but of course i get mostly garbage without term emulation.

Edit: I ended up implementing my own ascii escape code (a sub-set of VT100 essentially, with unsupported options parsed but ignored) and telnet server command parsing engine (it wasn't as difficult as I thought it would be), and also my own rendering code using the RichTextBox control, which was necessary due to limitations of silverlight on the phone which aren't there in either silverlight for the browser or WPF in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own terminal emulation/telnet negotiation code from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to contact Stefan Olson, who implemented a FlowDocument Viewer for Silverlight (unfortunately he didn't have time yet to clean it up and release the code):
http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Introduction-to-FlowDocument-for-Silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a technical layout, or a complete component? In regards to the flow layout, all you need is to represent text, so a `StackPanel` with TextBlock's in should work just fine.

A `TextBlock` can support multiple `Run` elements, which pratically gives you a flow-layout.

Either way, for a phone you should look into customizing the UI to suit your needs, rather than expecting a component to do it for you. If there was a component for it, there most likely would be a app for it, and then there wouldn't be a reason to write another app for it, would there now?-)

Comment: Well, I assumed it would involve either TextBlocks or the rich text control, but I'd need an implementation of the terminal emulation needed to make it work. So, not just putting the stream into a stackpanel (I'm already doing that) but interpreting all (or some good enough subset) of the control codes in the telnet standard. As an alternative, is there a telnet/terminal protocol reference anyone would recommend?

Comment: But you said you already have found such a library. Why not simply port it?

Comment: Amuse is a wpf app, and its implementation is wpf specific in enough ways to make a port to Silverlight on the phone practically a rewrite. If thats the best option, so be it. The question however was asking if anyone knows of a Silverlight specific or UI framework agnostic library.

Comment: You're still asking for a application, not a library. A library for telnet wouldn't include UI functionality. And again, surely the telnet functionality in Amuse isn't coupled with the UI? (if so, bitch at the author for being a shitty coder)